# Solve non-linear equations systems under restrictions with two parameters

Tags: systems-of-equations, parametric, nonlinear-system

I am doing scientific research and I have reached a point where I need to solve some equations in order to continue.

I have a system of 5 equations with 5 unknowns, two parameters and one constraint.

### These are my equations:

[image]

### Restrictions, constant and parameters:

[image]

The question is: How to solve a system of five parametric nonlinear equations in five variables subject to constraints, analytically expressing the result as a function of two parameters q and phi

I want to solve this using MatLab or Mathematica from Wolfram, I have also some knowledge in programming languages.

I need the both, the analytical solution and numerical solution for this matrix:

[image]

Thanks for reading, and please forgive my bad english...

Comment: Thanks for taking time to post your detailed Question. Is the $sen$ function (resp. $arcsen$ function) here the same as the sine function (inverse sine function)?  How many times will you want to solve this system, given revised values of $q,\varphi$?  Do you expect the solution to be unique, subject to the constraints listed?

Comment: Where is your try in Mathematica? Otherwise, it will be difficult to find help.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, "sen" is the "sine" in spanish. I think that possibly the solution is unique for each couple of parameter q,φ but I'm not sure.

Comment: I need analytical and numerical solutions, please see the matrix in the updated question.

Comment: @mmm I'm not sure how to explain my system in Mathematica or Matlab, because I'm don't know well the syntax

Comment: @hardmath Could you be so kind as to guide me in solving my problem? I don't know how to set it up in matlab

Comment: Please note that the substitution of the variables TL and TH of the equations XII and XIII, allows to simplify the resolution of V and VII.

Comment: My first interest will be investigating whether a solution is determined by these equations.  I did notice that XII and XIII allow $x,y$ to be eliminated in the first three equations, so the system is effectively three equations in three unknowns.   Once the nature of your parametric nonlinear system is clear, developing software such as Matlab modules to solve it robustly and efficiently is likely to be more of a programming task than a Question suited for Math.SE.

Comment: @hardmath Many thanks! What do you advise me to do?

Comment: "This question is not about mathematics"?! I firmly disagree, this question is about mathematics, speacilly applied mathematics. I think mathematics is not only a theory detached from practical applications. Put "on hold" my question which has received 3 upvotes is a small-minded action.

Comment: I've removed the tags for [tag:matlab] and [tag:mathematica] since the Question merely suggests these as possible software implementations, without any information specific to those.  On the suitability of Math.SE for questions about applications of mathematical software, see [this Meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9073/do-we-actually-welcome-questions-about-software-that-mathematicians-use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Corrigendum:**

The OP has provided a correction to equation VII, which should read:

$$ B_0(1+\sin \varphi)\left[\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\varphi\right)-\sin^{-1}(x+y)-(x+y)\sqrt{1-(x+y)^2}\right] \\
- \left[1+\sin \varphi - (x+y)\right]\cdot T_H^4 + \frac{q}{(4\pi + 8\varphi)R^2 \sigma(1-\gamma)} = 0 \tag{VII}$$

---

These equations present the nonlinear system to be solved in terms that match the intended (scientific or engineering) *application*.

Before jumping into software development to "solve" the system, which will in essence *rewrite* the equations in a form suitable for *programming*, it is a good idea to do an intermediate rewriting of the equations in a form suitable for *mathematical analysis* of the conditions which imply *existence* of solutions and their possible *uniqueness*.

While the distinction between physical constants and physical *parameters* is crucial to the application, it will be simpler for the sake of analysis to recast the equations using fewer terms (and thus losing in all likelihood the careful distinction between them as regards the application).

Note for example that the "constant" $B_0$ only appears multiplied by a factor $(1 + \sin \varphi)$.  Closer examination reveals we can divide through by the combined factor in equations V,VII,VIII in a way that reduces a good bit of "clutter".

Related observations can be made about the *unknowns* of the system.  We already commented that $x,y$ are explicitly determined by equations XII and XIII as expressions in $T_L,T_H$.  Thus those unknowns can be eliminated by substitution.  Furthermore $T_L,T_I,T_H$ only appear in the equations as fourth powers, so it will be simpler just to express conditions in terms of those fourth powers directly.

Thus our first task is undertaking a mathematical rewrite of the equations in hope of simplifying the analysis of existence and uniqueness of solutions.  Reasonably we can anticipate this will also facilitate the programming of solutions in a later undertaking.

For this particular *system* of equations we are indeed fortunate; simplifying the equations allows us to *solve* for the unknowns one at a time (not *simultaneous* as with most nonlinear systems).

To see this let's start with equation V, with only a minor simplification:

$$ B_0(1+\sin \varphi)\left[(\sin^{-1} x) + x\cdot \sqrt{1-x^2}\right]
-x\cdot T_L^4-\frac{q}{(4\pi + 8\varphi)R^2\sigma(1-\gamma)} = 0 $$

Note that the last term in the left hand side is just a constant, although it depends on the *parameter* $q$.  Thus we can divide through by $B_0(1+\sin \varphi)$ as suggested earlier and move the resulting constant term to the other side of the equation (with a change in sign):

$$ (\sin^{-1} x) + x\cdot \sqrt{1-x^2}-x\cdot \frac{T_L^4}{B_0(1+\sin \varphi)}
= \frac{q}{B_0(1+\sin \varphi)(4\pi + 8\varphi)R^2\sigma(1-\gamma)} $$

Now the right hand side can be replaced by a single constant, although we might want to use a notation that exhibits its dependence on both parameters $q$ and $\varphi$:

$$ L(q,\varphi) := \frac{q}{B_0(1+\sin \varphi)(4\pi + 8\varphi)R^2\sigma(1-\gamma)} $$

Moreover the left hand side can be further simplified (as a Comment by the OP may have indicated) using equation XII.  Squaring both sides of it and multiplying by four:

$$ \frac{T_L^4}{B_0(1+\sin \varphi)} = 4(1-x^2) $$

This looks like it was designed for the purpose of eliminating unknown $T_L$ from the simplified equation V.  Substituting in the left hand side and also in the right hand side:

$$ f(x) := (\sin^{-1} x) + x\cdot \sqrt{1-x^2}-x\cdot 4(1-x^2) = L(q,\varphi) $$

Remarkably the left hand side now depends only on $x$ while the right hand side is a value easily computed from parameters $q$ and $\varphi$, $L(q,\varphi) = q/[(1+\sin \varphi)(4\pi + 8\varphi)C_L]$ where:

$$ \begin{align*} C_L &:= B_0 R^2 \sigma (1-\gamma) \\
   & = (4.1\mathrm{E}9)(6.6\mathrm{E}6)^2(5.67\mathrm{E}{-8})(0.6) \\
   & = 6.07583592\mathrm{E}{15} \end{align*} $$

Stepping back from the equation itself, consider the domain allowed for unknown $x$.  Clearly we need $x\in [0,1]$, although not all those values admit solutions to the remaining equations.

As a check on our work so far, let's graph the function $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$.

[image: function f(x) on unit interval]
*Fig. 1*  A graph of $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$

The sample values given in the Question for parameters $q,\varphi$ suggest that the values $L(q,\varphi)$ will be positive.  In any case the equation $f(x) = L(q,\varphi)$ has a unique solution $x\in [0,1]$ exists when $0\lt L(q,\varphi) \le \pi/2$.  For the given sample values we can find such a solution $x$, such as the entry $q = 1.0\mathrm{E}{15}$ and $\varphi = 0$, for which:

$$ L(1.0\mathrm{E}{15}, 0) \approx 0.0121319 $$

The numerical solution $x \approx 0.745165$ can be found by simple [root-finding algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm).

In commenting on this Answer the OP requests "the analytical solutions".  This seems impractical.  The function defined as inverse to $f(x)$ has no elementary form and is of no advantage since the numerical solution can be easily computed to any desired precision.  The constants and parameters of this problem are not given to any particularly high precision, so carrying out the corresponding solution's precision to exceptional accuracy would seem pointless.

Likely we can solve equations VII and XIII for $x+y$ in a manner similar to how above we solved equations V and XII for $x$.  If $y = (x+y) - x$ turns out to be positive, then also $T_L \gt T_H$ can be attained.  After a unique value $T_I$ is obtained from equation VIII, we are done solving once we check to see if it satisfies the inequality:

$$ T_L \gt T_I \gt T_H $$

Comment: awesome, let me know if you update your answer please, and thanks again!

Comment: wow! You are a really talented person, a true math authority. My goal is the analytical solutions, ie of the type x = x (q, phi) and the same for the other unknowns. Could you help me to achieve my goal, please?

Comment: I really appreciate your thorough math knowledge and your time! Finally, either by numerical or analytical method it is essential to be able to graphically represent the solutions of "x", "y", "TL", "TI" and "TH", for a "constellation" of values of (q, phi), more detailed than those of my matrix (q-phi). If you can commit that, I can pay 100 USD (which for me is not a lower figure, because I live and study in Venezuela, where unfortunately there is now a severe hyperinflation).

Comment: @alessadro:  Thanks.  I would be happy to help you with programming, but you would need to figure out how to contact me directly, not through Math.SE.  I will continue to update the Answer, and you are welcome to ask for clarification at any time.

Comment: Alright, please note: when you will test some values of q-phi, more specifically for some values of q, imaginary or complex solutions for x or y may appear, that will not be valid or significant.